# Passing a UIIImage to UIImagePickerController for editing

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to provide UIImagePickerController a UIIMage object, to use editing functionality provide this pickerController.

This is how I am trying to implement it.

```
-(IBAction) openEditor:(id) sender{
    UIImagePickerController *pickerCntrl=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerCntrl.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    pickerCntrl.allowsEditing=YES;
    [self presentViewController:pickerCntrl animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But, for this Image must be already present in the Album. Another thing is it provides a UI for you to select the Image.

I am trying to open directly the following window on **openEditor:(id) sender**.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` is for picking an image (either from the photo library or the camera). It can't be used for any kind of editing of any arbitrary image you wish to supply.

If you want to provide scaling and cropping of your own image then you must implement your own image editing controller.

Either implement your own or look into a 3rd party library that already does this. I've had good luck with the [Aviary SDK](https://github.com/AviaryInc/Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-iOS).

Comment: The image received from UIImagePicker is always of fixed size? Do you have better explanation for it.

Comment: If you allow editing, two images are returned from the `UIImagePickerController`. You can get the original image or you can get the editing image. See the docs for `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and find the reference to the `Editing Information Keys`.

Comment: Yes I see there are two Images, but for iPhone get Image of size Original Image is 720.000000 960.000000 while edited Image is always 640 * 640, but need to check what will be value for iPad.